# How to target a particular form in a loop of forms with different data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I'm working on an ecommerce project where I'm creating a product list by looping (ng-repeat, Angular Js). Each Product has got some description and "Add to Cart" button. I want to save the "Product Information" in webstorage.

Image : [Product List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGklx.png)

Comment: you can add some information to parent container of Add to cart button lets say 
i assign an integer 1 to Fotune basen 1kg and 2 to Plain basin 
in backward in java script i create a Associative array of items 
when any ADD TO CART button clicked just pick the parent integer value and look up in associative array for that item..... got it....

Comment: K. I get your method. I'm going to try. If it doesn't work I'll ask for help once gain. Thanks